# What exception handling should I use?

Tags: java, exception

I have a method in which I set some properties in a VO. The method looks some thing like below:

```
public void methodToPopulateVO(MyVO vo)
{
    BackendClass bClass = new BackendClass();
    vo.setA(bClass.getA()); //Line 1
    vo.setB(bClass.getB()); //Line 2
    vo.setC(bClass.getC()); //Line 3
}
```

Any of these methods `getA()`, `getB()`, `getC()` can throw an exception. My requirment is if `getA()` is throwing some exception still code at Line 2 and Line 3 should execute. This applies to each line (e.g. if Line 2 causes an exception, Line 3 should still execute). I can not change implemenatation of `BackendClass`. What exception handling technique should I implement which will have less performance impact, as performance is a measure factor for our application?

Note the real system has about 20 fields, not just 3.

Comment: What do you believe are the options?

Comment: Since you have to catch the exceptions, every solution (explicit catch, finally, well that's it) will be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
public void methodToPopulateVO(MyVO vo){
    BackendClass bClass = new BackendClass();
    try {
        vo.setA(bClass.getA()); //Line 1
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log(e);
    }
    // same for the next 2 method calls.
}
```

Now when `getA()` throws an exception, you log the event and keep on executing.

Answer (score 0):

yes you should use the exception handling cause any exception can throw your methods i.e.

```
setA(bClass.getA()); 
setB(bClass.getB()); 
setC(bClass.getC());
```

you should write within try and catch and use the appropriate exception class to handle it or use Exception class in catch ....